# TFS Build Step - Encountered error TF400893: Unable to contact the server. Please check your network connection and try again

Tags: logging, tfs, azure-devops, build, custom-build-step

When reviewing the build steps on an Azure DevOps build, when I click on a given build step to get the details, instead of seeing the build detail output, I get the error:

```
TF400893: Unable to contact the server. Please check your network connection and try again.
```

[image]

I've tried restarting my browser, I've tried using a different browser, and I've tried restarting the build agent on the build server, all to no avail.

How can I see the build step detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ensure the URL is secure (https, not http)

I noticed that this happens when the URL that I use to access the build server uses the `http` protocol. When I switch to use `https`, I can see full build detail:

Over `http`:

[image: Build step over http]

Over `https`:

[image]